# run python console script from heroku

Tags: python, heroku, heroku-cli

I've deployed a python script on heroku and I can run that in local terminal by

> heroku run python script.py

command, But when I close the local terminal the script has been stopped.

Is there a way to run deployed script through the heroku server and independent of local machine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reddy Abel Tintaya Conde's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71179495/354577) using `heroku run:detached` is good for ad hoc stuff.

But if your script should run continuously, automatically restarting when it fails, you should [define a process for it in your `Procfile`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#procfile-format). Such processes are often called `worker` processes:

```
worker: python script.py
```

Then you can scale your `worker` process up (or down) with [`heroku ps:scale`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-dyno-scale):

```
heroku ps:scale worker=1
```

Whether you run your script this way or via `heroku run:detached`, remember that this consumes free dyno hours or, if you are using paid dynos, incurs costs.

Comment: I defined a worker in proc file but the second command gives an error : 'Couldn't find that process type (worker).' whats the number 1 in front of the worker ?

Comment: (a) Is your `Procfile` called `Procfile` _exactly_? Not `procfile` or `Procfile.txt` or something? (b) Is it in the root (top) irectory of your project? (c) If you're asking about the 1 in `heroku ps:scale worker=1`, that is the number of dynos we're asking Heroku to scale to. That might be up or down, but we want one running dyno.

Answer (score 4):

You can check:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-run-detached

`heroku run:detached -t python script.py` should do the trick for you