# Heroku - Python integration

Tags: python, heroku

I have a script that I run locally on my laptop, which polls a server and if certain criteria are met, it sends an email. I guess like a heartbeat app of sorts.

The server is a Raspberry Pi, it has a public IP address which is all working fine.

Id like to host the python script on Heroku, so that it can run without my laptop having to be on the local network or always running.

Does anyone have experience of Heroku to show me how I can have the script hosted and running constantly?

My other query is that free tiers of Heroku go to sleep after 30 mins, so would essentially stop the script until getting an http request and spin up the instance once again.

Trying to find some form of elegant solution.

Many thanks for any advice you can give,

All the best,
Simon

Comment: give a try to `Google cloud platform`, you can create a virtual machine or more

Comment: "My other query is that free tiers of Heroku go to sleep after 30 mins"—only if you have a `web` dyno running. [If your app is just a worker it will not sleep](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#dyno-sleeping): "Apps that only utilise a free worker dyno do not sleep, because they do not respond to web requests. Be mindful of this as they may run 24/7 and consume from your pool of hours." [If you verify your account](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#free-dyno-hour-pool) you can get away with running your script 24/7 for free.

Comment: "Does anyone have experience of Heroku to show me how I can have the script hosted and running constantly?"—see [run python console script from heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71179456/354577), for example.

Comment: @Chris thanks mate for the info, so if I verify my account, I can get up to 1000 dyno hours free. 24x7x4 for example would get my little worker app running 672 hours each month, which would be well within the 1000 boundary.

If Im reading this, youve absolutely nailed it Chris, thankyou....it at least shows that it is possible, and not just some daft idea. Thankyou again, ill check out all your links and post back any results I get. Thankyou again.

Comment: By verifying your account and only running one worker dyno, yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Different approachs would be:

1- Cloud Functions

1. Create lambda function in a cloud provider with your python code (free tier elegible)
2. Trigger that function every once in a while

2- Get VM on Cloud

1. Go to AWS, GCP, etc
2. Get a free tier VM
3. Run server from there

Comment: Thanks @GabrielBoehme....the only problem is see is that it needs to be constantly running....as its realtime specific. If it was able to just poll every 2 mins for example, then it might miss certain triggers.

Im thinking now I might have to rethink the architecture. Run the local rPi, which  writes to a DB and a Lambda function every second that checks to see if the trigger should be fired and then run the python....its getting complicated :):):)

Comment: @Shodgson if you want to, I can help you with that project. Email me (contact info on bio)

Comment: Its an aircraft tracker, and Im checking to see when one is overhead to trigger the email. 
Working fine locally, just would like to have it remote so I can not have laptop on all the time and in transit.
Its a complicated one :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have ssh access, use `screen` to keep your script running.

Install screen :

```
sudo apt install screen
```

Open a new session:

```
screen -S session_name
```

Now, you can run whatever you want, then detach the session by pressing `Ctrl+A` then `D`

To go back to the session at any time, first list the active sessions:

```
screen -ls
```

Then resume the session using:

```
screen -r session_id_name
```

Comment: This is also good @AKMalkadi ! Hmmm, getting some better ideas here, thanks guys